# Can I use a custom field type icon instead of value?

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-foundation, custom-field-types, file-icons

I'm creating a new custom field type to go with my custom document library.

What I want to do is to have the column display a small icon upon meeting a certain condition, for example if the element has different permissions then the list(broken inheritance) it displays an icon instead of the usual true/false(yes/no).

Does anyone know/have a usefull example or site I could look this info up?

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, [this post](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/04/overriding-the-presentation-of-an-xslt-list-view-web-part.html) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

I think jQuery can help you in rendering this information. I have done it many times in SharePoint 2007 site.  Just verify the class of the TD that loads the information.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){

function dashboard()
{

//Display icons based on the status value.
$("td .ms-vb2:contains('Draft')").html("<img class='docStatus' src='/Style%20Library/Images/draft.png' id='docStatusDraft' alt='Draft'/>");

$("td .ms-vb2:contains('Detail')").html("<img class='docStatus' src='/Style%20Library/Images/detail.png' id='docStatusDetail' alt='Detail'/>");

$("td .ms-vb2:contains('Fixed')").html("<img class='docStatus' src='/Style%20Library/Images/fixed.png' id='docStatusFixed' alt='Fixed'/>");

}

dashboard();

}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article on our company blog about the various ways of achieving this. The **Download** option would probably best fit what you're looking for.

[How to create a SharePoint KPI column](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-kpi-column/)

**Free:**

- ***Javascript***: Do the work on the client-side
- ***Designer***: Customise the list view using SharePoint Designer
- ***Download***: Download an open source Custom Field Type
- ***Code***: Create a custom field type from scratch

**Not free:**

- ***Enterprise Edition***: Use the Out of The Box Enterprise Edition functionality
- ***Buy***: Buy a pre-made Custom Field Type... We just so happen to sell one of these. :)

Links and more information on each of these options can be found in the article.

It sounds like you're going to have a bit of an uphill struggle with the broken permissions aspect: Our product (Highlighter) doesn't cover this functionality.

The property [`SPListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.hasuniqueroleassignments) will probably be of use to you.