# Can I use icons instead of text for Managed Metadata?

Tags: managed-metadata

As an example, is there a way to use a managed metadata for languages spoken, but when viewing the list, the column would show a flag thumbnail instead of the text entry?

It looks like this is close, but I don't see how it could support multiple icons: [Can I use a custom field type icon instead of value?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40028/can-i-use-a-custom-field-type-icon-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using JsLink. Suppose the Managed Metadata column has these terms

[image]

Save the flag images with the same name as terms somewhere in the library on in the layouts folder. A sample jslink code is below for list view.

```
CustomizeFieldRendering = function () {  
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        Templates: {
            Fields: {
                'MM': {
                    'View':function(ctx) {
                      return "<img src='http://site_url/_layouts/15/images/"+ctx.CurrentItem.MM.Label+".png' width='50px'/>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}; 

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeFieldRendering, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

and the output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, got me off to a good start, but how does this handle multiple terms?  In this scenario, if an item had both the "Australia" & "New Zealand" terms, then the images don't work.  I am seeing that it would change from ctx.CurrentItem.MM.Label -> ctx.CurrentItem.MM.Label[0], but I'm not sure how to do the multiple images.

Comment: Inside the 'View' function:

`code
 if (ctx.CurrentItem.MM[0]){
  var mText = ""; 
  for(i=0; i<ctx.CurrentItem.MM.length; i++){
   mText = mText + "<img src='http://site_url/_layouts/15/images/"+ctx.CurrentItem.MM[i].Label+".png' width='50px'/>"
  }
  return mText;
 }`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand code highlighting in comments for stackexchange yet... anyways, above comment should fix for multiple images & if there is an item without a metadata term(blank).